# Blender 2.8 - WorkBench - Gradients appear very low quality

Tags: workbench-render-engine

I'm building some models for a game that doesn't have any light sources so all the shadows and highlights are painted into the texture. Because I don't need any light sources I'm using WorkBench as the Render Engine as my understanding is that this Render Engine just prints the texture on the model similar to how "Texture View" did it in previous versions. So far so good, but what I'm noticing is that the gradients from the texture are much lower quality when I'm viewing the render in the viewport than they are in the actual texture file. Any idea why that might be happening? Thanks!

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- check your monitor/graphic driver color profile
- check your image texture or it's color profile
- check blender color management

Comment: Alright, will give it a try, thanks!